# Serving Images to get a request

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, get

I am using CodeIgniter rest Controller. I want to be able to serve images on GET requests made by the client.

Is this the best option or should i just provide a link to the image and let the client download it themselves?
If I can serve the images itself, than how should I?

Comment: `Header("Location: $imgUrl") ` in your controller would do the trick.

Comment: You want to send the image directly to the browser from the script?

Comment: Rolic. Yeah coz its an rest api which the client call to get images, SO being able to serve directly would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make CodeIgniter set the proper headers and such you could do this in your controller:

```
$this->output->set_content_type('jpeg')->set_output(file_get_contents('path_to_file'));
```

And it will output (as request response) the image content as a file. No view required.

Please note though that this is a bit of extra overhead as the file is processed by PHP instead of just the webserver (Apache/Nginx). It only makes sense if you need to have some business logic on the request, such as logging or authorization (though even that can be done without PHP). If you are just outputing the image it is therefor better to link straight to file and leave PHP out of it.

Comment: Really Appreciate it. I would prefer the second option. Can you please let me know as to how can I set a link to a image file. And secondly Will it be possible for apps on android and iphone to be able download it. And Yes I would like authentication.

Comment: @SaranshMohapatra You will have to do the complete solution yourself as I have no idea what your paths are. Also, please accept the solution if you like it.

Comment: No the thing is I dont want the paths to be know by the user. Thats why i was thinking if there is a way?

Comment: Well then you have to load and output the image in PHP like the example above. You can control the path to the file using routing and controller logic.

Comment: Thanks. Just one more thing. does thins change the quality of the image

Answer (score 0):

I think You could show the images to client and give them a check-boxes to download the images  as a Zip file.

See [this](http://www.9lessons.info/2012/06/creating-zip-file-with-php.html)

Comment: No I dont want an zip file thing. I just want normal images.