# Resizing an image on the fly in CodeIgniter without using CI image manipulation functions

Tags: php, codeigniter, gd, imagelibrary

I am trying to resize an image that is being fetched from a location on the server.

The CI image manipulation method works very good. But i need something like this

```
localhost/images/hello.jpg -width=500&height=450
```

or

```
localhost/images/imageresizer?path=http://localhost/images/hello.png&width=500&height=450
```

I know the first one looks wiered, but i just want to know if any other good methods exists other than image_lib in CI

> Using Ci image_lib the image simply displays on the browser, but
>   rather than displaying it i need to output a url to the image in json.
>   So that front-end developers can display them on their devices

please suggest

Thank you.

Comment: suggest... what have you tried so far?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819524/a-very-good-php-image-resize-script-suggestion

Comment: I mentioned in the Quoted text. i also tried using gd imagecreate also.. You want me to paste the code here? Apologize me if my question  is not framed correctly.

Comment: You do know you can output raw image data from php? Just change the headers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246246/serving-images-to-get-a-request and then use the php file in the `<img src="/index.php?/controller/function/300/500">` tag

And there are so much more ways.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out [Codeigniter Advanced Images](https://github.com/jenssegers/codeigniter-advanced-images). It has worked perfectly for me. You only have to note that the uploads folder has to be in the same location as the index.php page. Also, the folder name  and controller name have to be the same. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
function resize($path="", $width="", $height="", $type=""){
    if($path AND $width AND $height AND $type){
        $decoded_path = base64_decode($path);
        //resize
        header("Content-type:image/$type");
        echo $image;
    }
}
```

--

```
$image_path = "/var/www/images/test.png";

<img src="<?php echo "http://example.com/app/resize/" . base64_encode($image_path) . "/500/200/png"; ?>" alt="my resized image">
```